# calculation of $\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}(x^2+3x+2)}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

> Calculation of $$\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}(x^2+3x+2)}dx$$

My Try: Let $$I = \int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}(x+1)(x+2)}dx$$

Put $x=\sin^2 \theta$ and $dx = 2\sin \theta \cos \theta$ and changing limits

So $$I = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{2}{(1+\sin^2 \theta)(2+\sin^2 \theta)}d\theta$$

Could someone help me to solve it , Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\frac{I}{2}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{1+\sin^2\theta}-\frac{1}{2+\sin^2\theta}\right)d\theta,$$and with $t=\tan\theta$ we have $\sin^2\theta=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$ so $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{k+\sin^2\theta}=\frac{1}{k+1}\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{\frac{k}{k+1}+t^2}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{k(k+1)}},$$so$$I=\pi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right).$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{2}{(1+\sin^2 \theta)(2+\sin^2 \theta)}
=\frac{2}{1+\sin^2 \theta}-\frac{2}{2+\sin^2 \theta}.$$
Moreover, for $k>0$,
$$\frac{1}{k+\sin^2 \theta}=\frac{\frac{1}{k}d(\tan  \theta)}{1+\frac{(k+1)\tan^2 \theta}{k}}.$$
Finally let $t=\frac{\sqrt{k+1}\tan \theta}{\sqrt{k}}.$